# Rails: Stripe accept payment workflow

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe using the elements workflow.

Below are the steps that a user does

1. Select the plan
2. Enter card details and click 'Subscribe'

When the user clicks "Subscribe", in the backend I

1. create a subscription and return the clientSecret
2. call `confirmCardPayment` by using the clientSecret in step 1
3. on success of step 2, pass the paymentIntentId to backend to fetch the card details and save it in the user record.

Below is part of the code

```
  $(document).on('click', '#payment-btn', (e) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let name = document.querySelector('#name_on_card').value;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/subscriptions',
      method: 'POST',
      beforeSend: function(request){
        request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
      },
      data: {
        plan_id: plan_id
      }
    }).then((res) => {
      stripe.confirmCardPayment(res.clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: card,
          billing_details: {
            name: name
          }
        }
      }).then((result) => {
        if(result.error) {
          alert(result.error.message);
        } else {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/user',
            method: 'PATCH',
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(request){
              request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
            },
            data: {
              stripe_customer_payment_method_id: result.paymentIntent.payment_method
            }
          }).then((result) => {
            Turbolinks.visit('/videos?message=success');
          })
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Would this be a good way to execute the payments workflow or is there a more efficient way, may be i am missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is general approach for custom Stripe payment flows. See the [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/elements) for this here. There's often a server side component required to create the Payment Intent (or in this case a Subscription), which is then confirmed on the client by your end user, fulfilling any required payment authentication.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I was thinking of an edge case where, how should i handle the scenario where `stripe.confirmCardPayment` succeeded but user updated failed for some reason. So in such case user will not have any card details but there will be a subscription